# Assign an issue to multiple projects in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I have multiple websites that I work on. I set up each website as a Project in Redmine.  I share a lot of code across these multiple sites.  Is it possible to assign an issue to multiple projects? Or what would you recommend doing if you are working on something that goes across multiple projects.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of this redmine plugin:

https://github.com/nanego/redmine_multiprojects_issue

You should give it a try as it has been written exactly for this use case.

Comment: My biggest concern with this plug-in is that it depends on 2 other plug-ins as well. We only have around 8 plug-ins but upgrading to RM4 took weeks of testing and patching because of them. I definitely don't feel like adding 3 more moving parts for this very basic feature :(